# pdf file that can't delete, need solution on delete the pdf file

Tags: pdf

I can't delete this been trying to delete, force delete using cmd, rename, change location, anyone had any solution on this? When trying to delete the file is not showing any error. I had also tried to boot into safe mode to delete the file.

[can't delete the pdf picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wizeV.png)

Comment: Make a new user (member of Administrators), log into the new user and delete the file that way.

Comment: Looks like the filename (+path) is too long for the legacy APIs that most of Windows unfortunately still use.

Comment: Try opening PowerShell and entering this command: `Remove-Item Desktop\APz*.pdf`

Comment: the result i get is cannot find path

Answer (score 0):

- First, see if something is locking the file. Third-party tools, such as the free [Crystal Rich LockHunter](https://lockhunter.com/), make this easy, and also have *delete* features.
- Second, try to delete it from CMD as Administrator [using the Windows 8.3 filename alias](https://digitalsupport.ge.com/en_US/Article/Is-Windows-8-3-File-Naming-Enabled-How-Do-I-Enable-8-3-File-Naming-If-It-Is-Not).
- Third, boot from a Live USB, such as [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). Mount the HDD, and delete the file in the OS file manager (explorer). It is far easier to use the boot USB than to create a new Administrator user and then delete it.

**N.B.** Though you state you tried to "force delete using cmd, rename, change location," you were not specific in what you did, so these hints may be redundant. Try to explain *how* you performed these -- as Administrator? Using filename alias? Checking for locks?

Comment: Rather than point your comment to a video, explain how it was solved as an *answer*.